# Xeon Phi and Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, opencl, mpi

I am looking at a surprising number of low-cost $100 Xeon Phi "cluster in a board" PCI cards on eBay. Can these be used from an Ubuntu Server host to dispatch numerical computing tasks, or is CentOS/RHEL/Windows required instead?

Any pointer to tutorials for using Xeon Phi on Ubuntu appreciated.

Can Multiple Phi boards be managed from the same host system?

Is it possible to address the individual cores as traditionally done via MPI by hostname, or is OpenCL required? I guess what I am asking is... can you SSH to the individual cores?

Comment: It  looks like CentOS is the popular choice. Any Ubuntu-centric resources appreciated, I would like to find out if Ubuntu is a viable option here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tutorial of 14.04 vintage: [Getting Started with the Intel Xeon Phi on Ubuntu 14.04](http://arrayfire.com/getting-started-with-the-intel-xeon-phi-on-ubuntu-14-04linux-kernel-3-13-0/)

Other interesting resources:

[How to run Intel MPI on the Intel Xeon Phi Coprocessor](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/how-to-run-intel-mpi-on-xeon-phi.html)

[Using the Intel MPI Library on Intel Xeon Phi Coprocessor Systems](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/using-the-intel-mpi-library-on-intel-xeon-phi-coprocessor-systems.html)

[Using MPI and Xeon Phi Offload Together](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/using-mpi-and-xeon-phi-offload-together.html)

Comment: There are tutorials out there, but the Ubuntu-based material seems to be scarce... :-/